# How to disable NestJs Caching API responses

Tags: node.js, express, caching, nestjs

I have a normal NestJs application. I have a couple of APIs in it. Lately, I noticed that when I am testing them using Postman, the responses are being cached.

For eg.

```
I hit API-1 ... it gives me a response. 
I hit API-2 ... it gives me the response plus the previous response.
```

Is there a tweak to disable this?

Thanks in advance.

**This is API-1 which returns a normal response.**

[image: API-1]

**This is API-2 which returns the response of the previous API-1**

[image: API-1]

Comment: What version of Postman are you using? Can you show where you think it's getting cached?

Comment: using v7.23.0. Edited with the postman snaps.

Comment: Can you save both tabs and try again? Did you duplicate the tabs to create them or start from scratch on each one? Have you tried creating that request in a new tab? If you open the Postman Console, you're be able to see what's getting sent each time, might be some more info in there.

Comment: Are you using the caching module? Nest doesn't cache data or requests by default, and even with the cache module, only `GET` requests are cached.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller({path: "product",scope: Scope.REQUEST})
```

I think this is the thing. Since node is single threaded it was not disposing my earlier instance and was using the same response variable over and over again. So my API-1 saved response to a variable called RESPONSE.

On the next request API-2 was using the same variable RESPONSE.

The RESPONSE variable structure was like this -

```
{
   status: bool,
   message: string,
   data: object
}
```

API-1 modified it to

```
{
   status: true,
   message: "Done",
   data: {"key":"value"}
}
```

However, API-2 was only using the first two keys.

```
{
   status: true,
   message: "Not done",
   data: {"key":"value"}
}
```

And hence got the third **data** key of the previous request.

Ideally, this should not happen. But after applying the scope thing it got solved.

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes

> Controllers can also have scope, which applies to all request method
>   handlers declared in that controller. Like provider scope, the scope
>   of a controller declares its lifetime. For a request-scoped
>   controller, a new instance is created for each inbound request, and
>   garbage-collected when the request has completed processing.